# Dynamic, Nested Replace

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and need to strip out quite a bit of data within a string.  Because of the nature and variability of the string, I think I'm needing to use multiple, nested REPLACE commands.  The problem is each REPLACE needs to build on the previous one.  Here is a sample of what I'm looking at:

```
<Paragraph><Replacement Id="40B"><Le><Run Foreground="#FFFF0000">Treatment by </Run></Le><Op isFreeText="True"><Run Foreground="#FFFF0000">test</Run></Op><Tr><Run Foreground="#FFFF0000">.  </Run></Tr></Replacement></Paragraph>
```

Essentially, I need it to return just the text outside of the <> brackets so for this example it would be:

```
Treatment by test.
```

Also, I wanted to mention that the strings inside the <> brackets can vary quite a bit for each row both by content and length, but it isn't relevant for what I'm needing other than making it more complex for replacing.

Here is what I've tried:

```
REPLACE(note,substring(note,patindex('<%>',note),CHARINDEX('>',note) - CHARINDEX('<',note) + 1),'')
```

And it returns:

```
<Replacement Id="40B"><Le><Run Foreground="#FFFF0000">Treatment by </Run></Le><Op isFreeText="True"><Run Foreground="#FFFF0000">test</Run></Op><Tr><Run Foreground="#FFFF0000">.  </Run></Tr></Replacement></Paragraph>
```

Somehow I need to keep going with replacing each of the <> brackets but don't know how to proceed.  Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: You don't want to do this in SQL.   You don't want to do this in regex.  cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Hogan I was just searching for that post to link it. :)

Comment: @JacobH -- personally I think it should be added to the hot links below the tags. :D

Comment: @rob -- to be fair to you -- sql-server has a built in xml parser -- use that.

Comment: I have to do this in SQL.

Comment: when you say in SQL do you mean SQL running on sql server?

Comment: I'm trying to use this code in a SQL Server table trigger to insert data into another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you have that string holding the HTML fragment available you could try to use something like:

```
SELECT convert(xml, '<Paragraph><Replacement Id="40B"><Le><Run Foreground="#FFFF0000">Treatment by </Run></Le><Op isFreeText="True"><Run Foreground="#FFFF0000">test</Run></Op><Tr><Run Foreground="#FFFF0000">.  </Run></Tr></Replacement></Paragraph>').value('/', 'varchar(255)') as stripped
```

You convert it to XML and then use the built in xml parser function "value".

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much!  Now I just need to figure out what all of that means!